# Performance issue while publishing package

Tags: acumatica

Publishing package in my local system is taking much longer time than expected. It is taking around 15-20 minutes to publish, and sometimes it is throwing an error, UNABLE TO READ DATA like this.

I also tried even after Restart Application from Apply Updates screen but still same issue. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to disable web site building.
In Visual Studio, go to web site property pages and deactivate the following 2 configurations:

Uncheck Build Web site as part of the solution
Before run startup page - no build.

See http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/make-compilation-of-extension-library.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, Simon.